# Set whose average of subsets is always square (cube, etc.)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Fix $n>1$. Is there a set $A$ consisting of $n$ (distinct) positive integers such that the average of any subset of $A$ is a square? (Feel free to replace "square" with "cube", "fourth power", etc.)

I don't have any motivation for this question - I just thought it would be cool if a large such set exists.